# Google Apps Script gets stuck on UrlFetchApp.fetch() -> no error, no timeout

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

my script has been running for months. Since 12 dic, it fails on UrlFetchApp.fetch()
no error, and no timeout. It remains waiting until GAS execution time limit is reached.
Does anybody know if google server has done any changes concerning to `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` behaviour?
There's no problems with requests done from Postman.

```
function MAquery(query, bearer = MY_BEARER) {
  var url = 'https://ecostruxure-machine-advisor.se.app/daas/graphql'
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(query))

  url = encodeURI(url);

  if (typeof (query) == "string") {
    var data = { 'query': query }
  } else if (typeof (query) == "object") {
    var data = query
  }

  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    'headers': {
      "authorization": bearer,
      "content-type": "application/json",
      //"muteHttpExceptions": true,
    },
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data),
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var datos = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return datos;
}
```

After last tests,
it appears to be something related with an internet vulnerabilty. https://securityboulevard.com/2021/12/log4j-the-facts-behind-the-latest-zero-day-internet-vulnerability/

changing the user-agent header requests are attended. The user-agent used by GAS is refused by API's server. Copying it on Postman gets stuck as from GAS. I hope this is only a temporary change on API's server, made to avoid vulnerability, or Google changes his user-agent header.

Comment: Have you tested urlfetch with other urls in a separate project?

Comment: Yes, no problems with these url's:    https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=murcia,es&appid=*********   
http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=*******&query=Madrid